# how to clear NSFetchedResultsController results from UITableView in Restkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, restkit

I have a master `UITableView`, *programs*, and each cell clicked leads to another `UITableView`: *episodes* pertaining to the clicked program.

**problem:** every time i click on a program cell, it appends the episodes from the last program i clicked on to the episodes table view controller.

example: suppose program A has episodes i, ii, then clicking on episode A displays i,ii on the tableView
suppose program B has episodes iii, then clicking on episode B displays i, ii, iii rather than just iii

**what i tried:** i ensured that i always instantiate the EpisodesDataSource from scratch everytime i click on a programcell, and i've destroyed the NSFetchedResultsController instance every time i clicked on program cell. I've also ensured that I'm not adding the same response descriptor more than once.. and i've also used

```
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Master"];
```

everytime i call `fetchedResultsController`.. but still no luck.. see below for implementation details.

In **ProgramsViewController**:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Controller *controller = [Controller getSingleton];

    MediaListViewController *episodesVC = 
    [controller.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsReportsViewController"];
    ProgramCell *programCell = (ProgramCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    episodesVC.dataSource = [[EpisodesDataSource alloc] initWithProgramId:programCell.programId];

    [self.navigationController episodesVC animated:YES];
}
```

In **EpisodesDataSource**

```
@implementation EpisodesDataSource

- (id)initWithProgramId:(NSNumber *)programId {
    self = [self init];
    self.programId = programId;
    self.parameters = @{@"pid": programId};
    self.predicate = @"episode";
    return self;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    self.entityName = @"Episodes";
    self.resourcePath = kEpisodesPath;
    self.sortKey = @"episode_title";
    self.keyPath = @"EpisodesList.Episode";
    return self;
}

- (void)addResponseDescriptor {

    Model *model = [Model getSingleton];
    NSArray *existingResponseDescriptors = [model.objectManager.responseDescriptors mapObjectsUsingBlock:^(RKResponseDescriptor *descriptor, NSUInteger idx){
        return [descriptor keyPath];
    }];

    if ([existingResponseDescriptors containsObject:self.keyPath]) {
        NSLog(@"response descriptor %@ already exsits! return", self.keyPath);
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"adding response descriptor %@", self.keyPath);
    RKEntityMapping *episodesEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:self.entityName inManagedObjectStore:model.managedObjectStore];
    // left is http, right is dbase
    [episodesEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"programId.text":       @"episode_id",
                                                                @"EpisodeTitle.text":    @"episode_title",
                                                                @"EpisodeImageUrl.text": @"episode_image_url",
                                                                @"EpisodeNewsUrl.text":  @"episode_news_url",
                                                                @"EpisodeVideoUrl.text": @"episode_video_url",
                                                                @"EpisodeVideoId.text":  @"episode_video_id",
                                                                @"EpisodeCaption.text":  @"episode_caption",
                                                                @"EpisodeDetails.text":  @"episode_details",
                                                                }];

    episodesEntityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"episode_id" ];


    RKResponseDescriptor *episodesResponseDescriptor =
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:episodesEntityMapping
                                                 method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                            pathPattern:self.resourcePath
                                                keyPath:self.keyPath
                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];


    [model.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:episodesResponseDescriptor];

}
```

and in **MediaListViewController**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // setup delegates
    NSAssert(dataSource, @"Datasource of MediaListViewController cannot be nil");
    dataSource.tableViewController = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = dataSource;

    // setup refresh controller
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;

    // load data
    [dataSource addResponseDescriptor];
    [dataSource downloadData];
    Controller *controller = [Controller getSingleton];
    UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:controller.window.frame];
    [background setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [background setTag:999];
    [[self.tableView superview] addSubview:background];
    [[self.tableView superview] sendSubviewToBack:background];
}
```

**EpisodesDataSource** inherits from **DataSource:** which has:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    // reset
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Master"];

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *context =((Model *)[Model getSingleton]).managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:self.entityName
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:self.sortKey ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController
    = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                          managedObjectContext:context
                                            sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                     cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [tableViewController.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [tableViewController.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: It's not obvious what you are doing but why don't you have a predicate on the fetchedResultsController?  I would expect there to be some sort of predicate to select the episodes relevant only to the program. So something like `@"program == %@", program`.  It looks like you add episodes to Core Data each time and then use the fetchedResultsController to display them in the Episodes tableView.  So each time you pull back all episodes previously loaded.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald hey yeah i just did try the predicate solution (i had to update the service so that it actually includes the program id in each episode).. it works.. but now the problem is that i must click on the same program cell twice for it to load the programs (ie i click on it the first time.. nothing shows up.. i go back.. i click on it again and it works! i don't know why though)

Comment: Do some debugging. Does pull to refresh show the items? When selected, is the correct data passed and used in the predicate?

Comment: @wain i've ensured that the predicate is searching for the right *programid*.. also interestingly enough.. on first load even if i pull to refresh 100 times it doesn't load anything (always returns 0 results).. but when i load it again it works just fine.. 

the pattern i'm seeing is that on first load it's fetching data but all the data fails to pass the predicate test (proof: if i remove the predicate test it fetched all the data.. but then it also fetched the data of the previous programs as well).. but then when i load it again it passes the predicate test..

Comment: And you logged all the objects to check the id is set? Do you get any fetch error?

Comment: @Wain the code above shows that i do log the fetch error, but one happens. I'm not sure how to log the objects being fetched *before* the predicate is applied.. since the predicate is set onto the fetch before the fetch is instantiated.. could it have something to do with the context?

Comment: if it means anything.. [here](http://pastebin.com/pQcQSLVG) is my log statements basically keeping track of the data source object pointer and stuff.. it basically logs clicking on the first cell -> getting 0 results.. then it logs clicking on the first cell again and getting 2 results.. (each attempt is seperated by ----).. then i repeat the above again with the second cell with the same results as the first

Comment: I meant without the predicate applied, log the objects to check what they contain.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48586/discussion-between-abbood-and-wain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment from @Duncan Groenewald, you should be using a predicate to filter out the contents of the data store so you are only displaying a subset. Currently you display all content to each time a new download is processed you get additional table view content.

---

For the follow on issues, check the predicate. Mismatches in the class / data type used in the managed object and the predicate can cause failures when you expect matches (i.e. comparing the string "100" with the number 100).

Generally, all of the same type of information in your managed objects should match on data types, and when moving from master to detail interfaces you should pass the managed object (or value from a managed object) to ensure that you maintain consistency when fetching / filtering.

Comment: as per the predicate comment.. i think i got lucky b/c i also have control over the backend.. so i made the episodes entity contain the program id it belonged to.. but i was wondering how i would address this issue if i didn't have that kind of control..

Comment: You mean no control to match data types? Or no control over data from a server?

Comment: Depends very much on the situation. A badly designed server API can be crippling...

Comment: i thought about it a bit.. i figured what i can do is that even if the api doesn't have a program id in the episode resource.. I can manually store that into the episode resource using [Custom Primitive Accessor Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdAccessorMethods.html) similar to [this](https://gist.github.com/abbood/9266666) code.. then i can filter it using a predicate as instructed above.. haven't tested that idea though yet